# Получить массив всех элементов обрабатываемых рекурсивной функцией

Tags: php

Рекурсивная функция обрабатывает массив с подмассивами. Все элементы обрабатываются и распечатываются на экране. Но нужно все элементы переместить в один массив, без подкатегорий.

```
function recursCategoryS($array, $parent ){

  if(is_array($array)){

    foreach( $array as $kay => $category ){

      if( is_int( $kay ) ){

        if( isset($category['Группы'])  ){

          recursCategoryS($category['Группы']['Группа'], $category['Наименование'] );                 
        }    

      }else{

        if( isset($array['Группы'])  ){

          recursCategoryS($array['Группы']['Группа'], $array['Наименование']);               
          break;               
        }           
      }          
    }            
  } 
}
```

Массивы имеют значения:

```
                  [9] => Array
                    (
                        [Ид] => 28f98f1a-d622-11e5-9eb6-3085a9a964c4
                        [Наименование] => Samsung Galaxy A5 (2016)
                        [Группы] => Array
                            (
                                [Группа] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => Array
                                            (
                                                [Ид] => e5b33f89-eaab-11e5-84d9-3085a9a964c4
                                                [Наименование] => Панели, бампера и силиконовые чехлы
                                            )

                                        [1] => Array
                                            (
                                                [Ид] => e5b33f8b-eaab-11e5-84d9-3085a9a964c4
                                                [Наименование] => Футляры и чехлы-книжки
                                            )

                                    )

                            )
```

```
Array
(
    [Ид] => 32a9b398-22c7-11e4-a51e-3085a9a964c4
    [Наименование] => Аксессуары для старых телефонов
    [Группы] => Array
        (
            [Группа] => Array
                (
                    [Ид] => f3487b01-2204-11e4-a51e-3085a9a964c4
                    [Наименование] => Корпуса
                    [Группы] => Array
                        (
                            [Группа] => Array
                                (
                                    [Ид] => 6cb8a907-1831-11e1-b0ce-001dba279cde
                                    [Наименование] => Корпуса оригинал
                                    [Группы] => Array
                                        (
                                            [Группа] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [Ид] => 6cb8a912-1831-11e1-b0ce-001dba279cde
                                                    [Наименование] => Корпуса original для Nokia
                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Comment: А каким оператором *Все элементы распечатываются на экране* ?

Answer (score 0):

То что вы хотите сделать (если я правильно вас понял) обычно называется *flatten*. Если набрать в поиске `php array flatten`, то можно найти множество решений. В том числе и такое:

```
/**
 * Получение одномерного массива из многомерного
 * @param array $arr
 * @param bool $useKeys сохранять ключи (для одинаковых ключей значения перезапишутся)
 * @return array
 */
function arr_flatten(array $arr, bool $useKeys = false): array
{
    $it = new \RecursiveIteratorIterator(new \RecursiveArrayIterator($arr));
    return iterator_to_array($it, $useKeys);
}
```

В этом решении используются стандартные итераторы php. Но если вы хотите использовать рекурсивную функцию, то вам надо просто создавать массив, складывать в него значения не являющиеся массивом и возвращать его. Для значений массивов вызывать функцию рекурсивно и результат этого вызова сливать с массивом значений:

```
function arr_flatten($array)
{
    $result = [];
    foreach ($array as $v) {
        if (is_array($v)) {
            $result = array_merge($result, arr_flatten($v)); // рекурсия
        } else {
            $result[] = $v;
        }
    }

    return $result;
}
```

Это общий случай. В вашей структуре сплющивать надо как-то особенно, в зависимости от того есть ли ключ `Группы`. Но принцип совершенно такой же.